# Using MobX observable decorators with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, mobx

The [MobX docs](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/gh-pages/docs/best/syntax.md#enabling-decorators-in-your-transpiler) tell me I must "use the transform plugin transform-decorators-legacy and make sure it is first in the plugins list", in order for the decorators to work. The MobX boilerplate project suggests I need a `.babelrc` like:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "es2015",
    "stage-1"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", "react-hot-loader/babel"]
}
```

How do I do that with a create-react-app generated project? Any attempt to use `@` decorators errors. There is no `.babelrc` even after the project is 'ejected'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not use decorator syntax unless you [`eject`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#converting-to-a-custom-setup). However, you can use MobX without `@` since it is just a syntax sugar.

Dan Abramov [has articulated the reason for this](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/411#issuecomment-242740921)

> Our position is simple: we add transforms that are either stable
>   enough (like async/await) or heavily used by Facebook (like class
>   properties). Only that lets us be confident in suggesting them,
>   because if something changes in the standard, we’ll write and release
>   a codemod to migrate away from them.
>
> Since we don’t currently use decorators, we don’t take it upon
>   ourselves to provide a migration path if the standard becomes
>   incompatible. Additionally decorators aren’t even officially supported
>   by Babel (-legacy is there for a reason). And when they are configured
>   slightly incorrectly people blame React.

You also might want to look into [`create-react-app-mobx`](https://github.com/mobxjs/create-react-app-mobx/)

Related discussions:

- https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/214
- https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/521
- https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/411

Comment: See also for an example of MobX without decorators: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/214#issuecomment-236151343

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks, Dan! :)
And from the [MobX docs](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx#observable-state).

Comment: Created a small repository demonstrating how to add MobX to create-react-app without decorators: https://github.com/mobxjs/create-react-app-mobx

Comment: I did a small project with React App 2.0, Bable 7 with MobX with decorators WITHOUT EJECT !! : 
https://github.com/almog-kiki/react-mobx-page-animation

Answer (score 11):

There's an alternative now that was not available at the time of the accepted answer. It's [custom-react-scripts](http://custom-react-scripts.surge.sh/). It will let you enable decorators, SASS and other niceties in your CRA app. And it does so without ejecting.

There's a nice [medium article](https://medium.com/@kitze/configure-create-react-app-without-ejecting-d8450e96196a#.1m4snh6b0) explaining the ideas behind it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewire-mobx

React App Rewired will give you access to the config than you just need to setup the package.

```
npm install react-app-rewired --save

// create a file named config-overrides.js

/* config-overrides.js */

const rewireMobX = require('react-app-rewire-mobx');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config = rewireMobX(config, env);
  return config;
}
```

**Note:**
This saves you from ejecting.  CRA does not support modifying the config https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/99#issuecomment-234657710.

Answer (score 2):

Now, you can push `require.resolve('babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy')` in node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js plugins array

Answer (score 2):

This is the best solution I've found without ejecting. Replace create-react-scripts.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-react-scripts

If you have a new project start by using this in your terminal:

```
create-react-app my-app --scripts-version custom-react-scripts
```

Then cd into my-app directory and create a .env file. Edit the .env file to this:

```
REACT_APP_BABEL_STAGE_0=true
REACT_APP_DECORATORS=true
```

Your app will now support decorators.

If you have an existing app and want to add this. Add the .env like above then:

```
npm i custom-react-scripts --save
```

remove react-scripts in your package.json. Do not change the scripts from react-scripts start to create-react-scripts start. Leave the scripts as is.

now add your mobx stuff with decorators and enjoy less boilerplate code.

my final package.json

`{
  "name": "mobx-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "custom-react-scripts": "^0.2.1",
    "mobx": "^3.4.0",
    "mobx-react": "^4.3.5",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}`

oh and if you are using vscode you will want to hide the warnings about unsupported decorators. To do that add a tsconfig.json file to your project with this

`{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true
    }
}`