# mobx method annotation and babelrc plugin order

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app, mobx

trying to use decorators with Mobx in JS and as soon as trying to use method level decorators, i am getting:

"Syntax error: Method has decorators, put the decorator plugin before the classes one."

example code:

```
class TestStore {
    constructor(rootStore) {
        // we inject the rootStore to get other child stores if needed
        this.rootStore = rootStore
    }

    @observable fileList = [];
    @observable processedFile = null;

    @action doSomething() {
        console.log("work work");
    }
}
```

The error itself is very well documented in the web, but the problem is, i have the right configuration in place.... see my .babelrc

```
{
 "presets": [
  "env"
 ],
 "plugins": [
   "transform-decorators-legacy",
   "transform-class-properties"
 ]
}
```

I tried removing "env" preset cause i thought someone else is putting a class transformation in but this doesnt change anything.

To make that work with (latest) create-react-app i set babelrc: true in webpack.config.dev just for the sake of testing. Dont want to eject. To clearify: The decorator transformer is definitely picked up. Otherwise you get a different error.

I am clueless right now what else to do.

Comment: seems duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39262103/using-mobx-observable-decorators-with-create-react-app?rq=1

Comment: [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) with the [MobX extension](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/tree/master/packages/react-app-rewire-mobx) works great.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate link is correct. You simply cant easily add decorators to create-react-app. If you patch the webpack.config.dev.js and set **babelrc: true** you can put your own .babelrc in project root and it gets picked up, but still there are problems with the ordering of plugins because somehow the defined plugin gets loaded "too late". Some other plugins were already loaded which interfere with the decorator plugin.

There is a hacky answer to it. You can put **plugins: ["transform-decorators-legacy"]** Right inside webpack.config.dev.js. This way ordering is ok. But its not a good solution because overriding libararies in npm_modules is always bad.

In the long run i will eject or use rewired.