# React Class Decorators Don't Compile

Tags: reactjs

I've created a simple react app using the create-react-app cli tool

I've created a component called TodoList

```
export class TodoList extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Todo List</h1>
        );
    }
}

export default withLoader(TodoList);
```

And I wanted to apply a Higher Order Component to it, so I Created this HOC

```
const withLoader = (WrappedComponent) => {
    return class extends Component {
        render() {
            debugger;
            return (
                <div>
                    <h3>Loading...</h3>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default withLoader;
```

Here are my questions:

- The render function inside the withLoader HOC is never executed, why?
- Why when I use withLoader as a class decorator the code never compiles?

example

```
@withLoader
export class TodoList extends Component {}
```

this code snippet never compiles.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using MobX observable decorators with create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39262103/using-mobx-observable-decorators-with-create-react-app)

Comment: Please post the full code; from this I can't see how you are using TodoList. An interesting thing here is you are creating a higher order component (withLoader), that is taking the WrappedComponent as a parameter, but then isn't referring to it in its render function, so your TodoList won't be rendered at all.