# 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled Mobx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I have create config-overrides.js with the following code to enable decorates-legacy:

```
    const {
    addDecoratorsLegacy,
    override,
    disableEsLint
} = require("customize-cra");

module.exports = {
    webpack: override(
        addDecoratorsLegacy(),
        disableEsLint()
    )
};
```

I still have the same error mentioning that support for experimental syntax isnt currently enabled -> i used create react app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using MobX observable decorators with create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39262103/using-mobx-observable-decorators-with-create-react-app)

Comment: @Danila i have followed the following approach and still received same error -> https://www.robinwieruch.de/create-react-app-mobx-decorators